# ColdFusion convert hidden form variables to a structure

Tags: html, coldfusion

The app I am working on has hidden input variables set on initial load of the page. The variables need to be accessed across all pages. The reason for not converting these to session variables is the user can open another browser with different parameters and passing those value as hidden inputs make it work without any issue. What is the best possible alternative so as to get rid of these hidden inputs..I tried converting all variables into a Structure, but again the structure needs to be posted as part of form submission to make it available to subsequent pages.Another disadvantage of this app is use of frames.I don't have any code to post.

Comment: You need to decide what you want. Hidden input variables are only available to ColdFusion through a form submission. Session variables are needed to make data available to subsequent pages but they have the caveat you mentioned when a new browser is opened. Maybe I am not understanding your question?

Comment: you are right...hidden inputs are though prone to security risks...Is there any other alternative way to pass those form variables? Right now I created a new hidden variable that holds the encoded json string of all the hidden inputs. But the new variable is again a hidden input

Comment: If the original values of these variables come from user input, what exactly are you worried about?

Comment: instead of using the Session scope you could use the Request scope. All variables in this scope are available during that request

Comment: @XavierL., the request scope is probably not applicable because the OP is looking to preserve variables on subsequent requests.

Comment: @DanBracuk...its the issue with passing of these 15 to 20 variables on every page. if there is a way its set one time and can be accessed from subsequent pages from there on...is it possible to not overwrite session variables when a new browser window is opened?

Comment: The session variables are not overwritten when a new browser window is open. A new session is created when the new browser window is open. As far as the ColdFusion server is concerned it is a new user. If you need the level of control you are after you may need to enforce some sort of login for your users. That way you can keep track of who is who on each request. That would also allow you to use a database to store things for each user and retrieve/update that info as you wish throughout the application. Instead of being stuck with these anonymous form submissions.

Comment: So if I have a session variable that holds a value like tax_year. In browser 1, I select 2016 and then open browser 2 and select 2014. The value in browser 1 is updated to 2014 on refresh.

Comment: That is generally how it works when you open a new _tab_ of the existing browser window or keep the original browser window open. If you open a new browser window it will create a new session and the values of the original will not be updated. But in your question, isn't that behavior actually what you want? I still don't understand what your actual question or intended behavior is. [Edit] your question. Give us an example, with data, of how you want this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds as if you want different browsers instances which are associated with the same web session to maintain their own distinct sets of data.  Doing this by passing `form` or `url` variables around seems like a bad idea.

One approach that you could use would be, onSessionStart (or as required), create a structure in the users session to hold instances of the data.  For example

```
session.data = {
    someRandomKey: {
        valueA: 42,
        valueB: "Porridge"
    }
}
```

Then just pass `someRandomKey` as a hidden `form` field or querystring parameter. Now, when they submit the form to update variables you use the id from the hidden form field to find the appropriate structure from `session.data`.

When the user needs a new instance of this form, give them some way, like a link or button, that creates a new unique key, inserts a struct in  `session.data` with this key and populates it with whatever defaults are needed then loads the form passing along the new id as a hidden form field or querystring param again.